# Finding proper hangup reason in asterisk

Tags: lua, asterisk

I set up a hangup Handler in **extensions.lua**. On hangup That function also executing but my problem is i am not able to catch exact hangup code. Whether hangup happen by my dial plan or end user hangs up , Always I am getting 16 as hangup code. I am using asterisk with PRI card and all calls are through PRI only.

below is my code for hangup handler -

```
function my_custom_hangup_handler(c,e)
    app.NoOp('Inside Hangup Handler For:'..e)
    app.NoOp('Hangup Cause='..channel['HANGUPCAUSE']:get())
end
```

Also I am able to see RINGING Event in console. Is there any way to get those event in dialplan?

see below log

```
-- Called DAHDI/g0/888488XXXX
-- DAHDI/i1/888488XXXX-389 is proceeding passing it to Local/888488XXXX@local-channel-start-00000017;2
-- Local/888488XXXX@local-channel-start-00000017;1 is proceeding
-- DAHDI/i1/888488XXXX-389 is ringing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always set my own HANGUP_OWNER variable. You can make use of the "g" option when dialing to continue executing dialplan. Essentially, if you hangup, Asterisk will jump directly to the "h" extension of the current context, but if your callee hangs up, the "g" option tells asterisk to continue executing dialplan in that same context. Here is a modified version of my dialplan. Keep in mind you would have to do this anywhere you use the Dial() function:

```
[all-outbound]
exten = _X.,1,NoOp(Outgoing call from ${CALLERID(all)} to ${EXTEN})
exten = _X.,n,Set(HANGUP_OWNER=Caller)  ; we hung up
; dial out on the provider SIP trunk
exten = _X.,n,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN}@provider-sip,,g)
; must use dial option 'g' for hangup owner to work
exten => _X.,n,Set(HANGUP_OWNER=Callee)  ; they hung up
;....
;....
exten = h,1,NoOp(Hangup cause is ${HANGUPCAUSE})
exten = h,n,NoOp(Call Duration is ${CDR(duration)})
```

Also, it's worth pointing out that "us/them" reverses for inbound vs outbound, so it's helpful to update the comments. I keep the "caller/callee" verbiage to keep things simple, but it's nice to show exactly who is who in the comments.

Asterisk 13 [Dial docs](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+Application_Dial)

Comment: It am able to detect whether call is answered or not using this even earlier i use same to detect. but it is PRI and when user did not answer or did a hangup always i am getting CHANUNAVAIL always i want this event to detect properly

Comment: If you post the relevant piece of your dialplan I might be able to identify the issue. It sound like you might be dialing something else that is unavailable after the user hangs up?

Comment: I have talked with hardware provider regarding this and they told that PRI connectivity provider only passing hangup cause 31 in both events that's why I am getting CHANUNAVAIL.

Answer (score 0):

You can read DIALSTATUS variable.

If you hangup, should be CANCEL